# Direct ByteBuffer

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am testing out direct ByteBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) with JNI. So the code below tries to:

1. Put values into direct ByteBuffer in Java
2. Change the value in C++
3. Get the value in Java

I was wondering where exactly did I do wrong? The C++ code manage to get the data from Java but changes in C++ did not reflect back in Java.

This is what I did on java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3);
    byte[] b = {122,121,120};
    System.out.println("1: " + new String(b));
    bb.put(b);

    new JNI.process(bb);

    byte[] c = new byte[3];
    c[0] = bb.get();
    System.out.println("4: " + new String(c));
}
```

This is what I did on JNI function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MarsJNI_mapreduce
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobject output){
    char *out = (char*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(output);
    printf("2: %s\n", out);
    out = "ABC";
    printf("3: %s\n", out);
}
```

And the result I get is:

```
1: zyx
2: zyx
3: ABC
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:474)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:208)
    at MarsJNI.main(MarsJNI.java:21)
```

Comment: Apart from what @TedBigham mentions, you have the problem that your modifications will never make it into the original array

Comment: @fge are you referring to out = "ABC"; in the C++ code?

Comment: @TedBigham yes indeed

Comment: I suspected that too, but my C++ is pretty rusty.  I think he needs to do a strcpyn instead.

Comment: @TedBigham that would be `strncpy()` but that's the essence of the problem indeed

Comment: Indeed @fge is right bb.position(0) solves part of my problem (Forgot to mention this part). If I get the position right, I will get the following output 4 as zyx instead of ABC after the change.

Comment: Another thing: if you want to copy the contents of the buffer into the `c` array, what you should do is `buf.put(c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: see @TedBigham's answer. You can also use `buf.rewind()`.

Second problem: you only copy the first byte of the buffer into `c`, not the whole buffer. Do:

```
byte[] c = new byte[3];
bb.rewind();
bb.put(c);
System.out.println("4: " + new String(c));
```

Third problem: your C++ code does:

```
char *out = (char*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(output);
// ...
out = "ABC";
```

But what you do here is create `{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 0 }` and assign `out` to it; you don't actually modify the content of the buffer. You should do:

```
memcpy(out, "ABC", 3);
```

Fourth problem: when you create a `String` out of a `byte[]`, you should specify the encoding:

```
new String(c, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Whoa, you understood me completely from the start. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome ;) I have also found another problem... This one may be delicate to handle though. I don't know what C++' equivalent to Java's `char` is (`wchar_t`?), nor how it handles locales.

Comment: Is there any specific scenario where knowing the equivalence be helpful? I thought that through JNI, we shouldn't worry over this?

Comment: Depends; do you intend to manipulate text or pure bytes? If you manipulate text, yes, this should be a worry from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call bb.position(0) before you call bb.get()

Comment: Yup, that is one problem; there is another one however