# Writing to Java memory from C/C++

Tags: java, android, c++, memory, java-native-interface

I'm creating an image processing application for android. My image processor is written in C++ and I'm trying to use this in android through JNI. What I want is an efficient way to write a pixel buffer I have in C++ into an ImageView widget.

Currently I have a native function which takes a byte array as a parameter and does the required processing on this byte array.

**Java**

```
public native void GetPixelData(byte[] pixels);
```

(below is a pseudo code. I'm using correct function signatures/syntax in my code.)

**C++**

```
com_..._GetPixelData(env, jbyteArray pixels)
{
   jbyte* pixelData = env->GetByteArrayElements(pixels, NULL);
   if(pixelData != NULL)
   {
     // do the required processing on pixel array
     env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(..., JNI_COMMIT);
   }
}
```

and in java, I update a bitmap through Bitmap.SetPixels using these new pixel data.

Everything is working as expected but I read that GetByteArrayElements **may or may not** copy data. So, as I understand, in a case it does copy the byte array from java to C++ then it will have to copy back the changes as well. So that is two copies for this function. I call this GetPixelData function quite often in the application.

So my question is there any way I can

1. Get access to the byte array from C++ in a way that is guaranteed no copy will take place. Basically is there another function like GetByteArrayElements or any other method which never copies the data but returns a pointer to the data in java heap.

Also, is there any way I can get direct access to ImageView's internal buffer so I can modify it instead of copying to a bitmap and using the bitmap in the ImageView?

If there is no way to do this without those extra copies and if these copies affect the performance significantly, I'm willing to rewrite the image processor in java.

Comment: Could you use a direct `ByteBuffer` instead of a `byte[]` array? They are much easier to work with in native code

Comment: @Joni I didn't know about it. I just looked into it a bit and saw there's a method called something like GetDirectBufferAddress. Sounds really promising. Thanks for the tip. I'll dig deeper

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423147/direct-bytebuffer)

Comment: Yes I forgot to update this question. As @Joni suggested I looked into ByteBuffer. It did extacly what I wanted. GetDirectBufferAddress() gives a nice pointer that I can use to read/write in C++. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.